# Weird Access is is denied error when change Platform in ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, 64-bit, configurationmanager

I am working with Visual Studio 2019 in Windows 11.

I create a new Solution which only has 1 `Console App (.NET Framework)` Project. The Framework is `.NET Framework 4.7.2`.
So the Project's name is **ConsoleApp1** and it has 1 `App.config` and 1 `Program.cs` file.
And the Solution's name is also **ConsoleApp1**. I rebuild the solution and no errors.

Now this Project need to be used for x64 Platform. So I follow these steps:

1. I open ***Configuration Manager*** window. For the **ConsoleApp1** Project, the Configuration field is showing `Debug` and the Platform field is showing `Any CPU`.
2. I open the drop down of Platform field and click <New...> option which opens ***New Project Platform*** window. There I selected `x64` as New platform and `Any CPU` as Copy settings from. Click OK button which closes the ***New Project Platform*** window. Now in ***Configuration Manager*** window the Platform field of **ConsoleApp1** Project is showing `x64`.
3. I close  ***Configuration Manager*** window.

Now I rebuild the solution again but this time I get this error:

> Unable to copy file "obj\x64\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe" to
> "bin\x64\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe". Access to the path
> 'obj\x64\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe' is denied.

I dont understand this error. There is no other Visual Studio open. There is no other process accessing those folders. Why I am getting this error?

If I change the Project's Platform back to `Any CPU` then the rebuild the solution works and I get no errors. So it has to do something with `x64` Platform.

Comment: Use `ProcMon.exe` to see what processes are fighting over the same files. I'll bet you have some dodgy Roslyn analyzers or maybe overly-aggressive anti-virus software interfereing with MSBuild.

Comment: Have you set any folder permissions manually earlier? Maybe VS is creating the obj\x64 folder and has no permissions to access it because the permissions from the parent folder are not inherited?